# Cakephp controller not working in hosted server

Tags: php, cakephp, cpanel, cakephp-3.x

My cakephp project works perfectly on localhost, but doesn't work when I upload it to a hosted server.

This is the setup on my cPanel File Manager of hosted server:

```
/home/username/public_html/test
    // webroot contents goes here
    css/
    img/
    js/
    index.php

/home/username/mycakeapp/
    // necessary app directories go here
    /config
    /logs
    /plugins
    /src
    /tmp
    /vendor
```

I made sure to change WWW_ROOT in mycakeapp/config/paths.php on line 52:

```
define(‘WWW_ROOT’, ‘/home/username/public_html/test’ . DS);
```

I also changed index.php in public_html/test in the following 3 lines so that it correctly requires necessary files:

```
require '/home/username/mycakeapp/config/requirements.php';
require '/home/username/mycakeapp/vendor/autoload.php';
$server = new Server(new Application('/home/username/mycakeapp/config'));
```

After doing this, when i open the website.com/test, the site correctly opens the home.ctp file. However, upon going to other pages like website.com/test/users, it gives an error message like so:

```
The requested URL /test/users was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

My home.ctp file only has pure HTML code, so I guess it works fine. However, going to other sites which has CakePHP code, it doesn't seem to work at all. Plz help!

Comment: Did you upload the .htaccess file that defines the necessary URL rewrite rules?

Comment: @Joni no I wasn't aware that there is a .htaccess file. Is it necessary?

Comment: Has your autoload been updated for the host directory setup?

Comment: @Greg i didn't change anything from my autoload.php file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upload your .htaccess file.

The part that's not working is the one that rewrites requests for "pretty" URLs like /users into requests for PHP scripts like /index.php?q=/users. The .htaccess file does that.

Answer (score 0):

You should try changing `App.base` parameter in `./config/app.php` like so:

```php
'App' => [

    // ...
    'base' => '/test',
    // ...

]
```

See the documentation [here](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/configuration.html#general-configuration).